# fflush on pipe not working in awk

Tags: awk, pipe

Consider the following commands:

```
bash$ seq 1 3 | awk '{print $0 | "cat"; print "0"}'
0
0
0
1
2
3
bash$ seq 1 3 | awk '{print $0 | "cat"; fflush("cat"); print "0"}'
0
0
0
1
2
3
bash$ seq 1 3 | awk '{print $0 | "cat"; close("cat"); print "0"}'
1
0
2
0
3
0
```

Why does not the `fflush` command work here, whereas `close` works. That is: produces the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our old friend `strace` solves this mystery.

In the `fflush("cat")` case, awk quickly writes all three values while cat is still loading. When cat finishes loading, it reads all three values in sequence and writes them out at the same time.

In the case of `close("cat")`, awk waits for the process to exit, at which point cat is guaranteed to have read the value, written it, and exited.

I increased the numbers in the `fflush` case from 3 to 1000, and now `awk` reaches 120 before cat catches up, and from there on it works basically as you expect. It prints "1,2,..,120,1,2,...,120,121,121,122,122,123,123,...".

Note that you're not guaranteed to see numbers in perfect pairs. awk blocks until the number has been written to the pipe, but it doesn't wait for cat to do anything with it.

Answer (score 1):

Not really something I have much experience of but the gawk manual tells us:

> fflush([filename])
>   Flush any buffered output associated with filename,
>   which is either a file opened for writing or a shell command for
>   redirecting output **to a pipe** or coprocess.

Note that "cat" as used above is in none of the contexts the gawk manual says are affected by fflush().

The same manual for close() on the other hand says:

> close(filename [, how])
>   Close the file filename for input or output.
>   Alternatively, the argument may be a shell command that was used for
>   creating a coprocess, or for redirecting **to or from a pipe**; then
>   the coprocess or pipe is closed.

Note that the context in which you're using cat is redirecting **from** a pipe and so is included in the list of items affected by close() but not by fflush().

Comment: +1 Thanks. So if you want to mix output from `awk` with output from pipes, you should always close the pipes immediately (in order to get the correct output)?

Comment: Not really my strong point as I don't think I've ever had to do that so my opinion on it wouldn't be worth much. Sorry.